# Calling parent window function from child window not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have two `HTML` files on the same directory:

**parent.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_child_window() {
    var sayHello = function(name) {
        alert('Hello ' + name + '!');
    }
    var win = window.open('child.html');
    win.onload = function() {
        win.myCallbackFunction = sayHello;
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="open_child_window();">Open Child Window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function sayHelloParent() {
    myCallbackFunction('Susan');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="sayHelloParent();return false;">Say Hello on the Parent Window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

With the two codes above, I click: `Open Child Window` on the parent window. Then, when I click the link: `Say Hello on Parent Window` from the child window, I get an alert on the parent window with the proper message.

Now, my goal is that this is done automatically without having to click that link.

I tried different ways like `<body onload="..." ...>`, etc, with no success.

Any idea on how to get this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with calling the callback on the page load is the callback has not even been added to the child window, you can add a setTimeout to wait a short time until the function gets added.

This is because the parent.html's code runs after the page content loads, but also after it runs its code on load.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myCallbackFunction('Susan');
    }, 10)
});
```

I used the addEventListener function instead of onLoad, they should have the same functionality

Answer (score 1):

When the child window calls the function the parent may be not yet initialized.

That's why you should put **both** functions to **onLoad** in their windows, not only the in the child window.

Comment: the parent window was already initialized before I click the link on it. I never closed the parent window.

Comment: But you say you want to do it without click. Parent window creates child window when the parent window is not yet completely loaded. When child window calls parent, parent may be not yet initialized. To make sure the parent is initialized, create child not from HEAD, but from body, after it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

But you say you want to do it without click. Parent window creates child window when the parent window is not yet completely loaded. When child window calls parent, parent may be not yet initialized. To make sure the parent is initialized, create child not from HEAD, but from body, after it is loaded.